# Lauch4j doesn't copy launcher

Tags: java, windows, wrapper

I am making 2 java software build in exe by the launch4j-maven plugin.The plugins-parts in both pom.xml are the same (except for the apps name).
Strangly when i launch the first exe, lauch4j do it right: i can see myapps.exe running and in the log i see the copy:

```
Using 64-bit runtime.  
Check launcher: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe (OK)  
Copy:       C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe -> C:\Program          Files\Java\jre7\launch4j-tmp\NumSyncManager.exe  
Heap -Xms:  5 MB / 0%, Free: 892 MB, Heap size: 5 MB  
Heap -Xmx:  15 MB / 0%, Free: 892 MB, Heap size: 15 MB  
...  
Launcher:   C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\launch4j-tmp\NumSyncManager.exe  
Launcher args:  -Xms5m -Xmx15m -classpath "C:\Program iles\..."   
Args length:    474/32768 chars  
Exit code:  0
```

But when i launch the second one, i see javaw.exe instead of myapps2.exe and in the log I clearly see that it doesn't copy the launcher:

```
Using 64-bit runtime.  
Check launcher: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe (OK)  
Heap -Xms:  10 MB / 0%, Free: 951 MB, Heap size: 10 MB  
Heap -Xmx:  500 MB / 0%, Free: 951 MB, Heap size: 500 MB  
...  
Launcher:   C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe  
Launcher args:  -Xms10m -Xmx500m -classpath "C:\Program..."  
Args length:    817/32768 chars  
Exit code:  0
```

here the xml file of the working apps:

```
                    <configuration>
                        <headerType>gui</headerType>
                        <outfile>target/${winName}.exe</outfile>
                        <jar>target/${artifactId}-${version}-jar-with-dependencies.jar</jar> <!-- 'shaded' is the value set on shadedClassifierName above -->
                        <errTitle>Erreur lors du lancement du logiciel</errTitle>
                        <classPath>
                            <mainClass>fr.core.BootStrap</mainClass>
                        </classPath>
                        <singleInstance>
                            <mutexName>${winName}</mutexName>
                            <windowTitle>${winName}</windowTitle>
                        </singleInstance>
                        <jre>
                            <minVersion>1.6.0</minVersion>
                            <initialHeapSize>50</initialHeapSize>
                            <maxHeapSize>100</maxHeapSize>
                        </jre>
                        <versionInfo>
                            <fileVersion>${version}.0</fileVersion>
                            <txtFileVersion>${version}.0</txtFileVersion>
                            <fileDescription>Tool Manager</fileDescription>
                            <copyright>C</copyright>
                            <productVersion>${version}.0</productVersion>
                            <txtProductVersion>${version}.0</txtProductVersion>
                            <productName>${winName}</productName>
                            <internalName>${winName}</internalName>
                            <originalFilename>${winName}.exe</originalFilename>
                        </versionInfo>
                    </configuration>
```

And here is the xml of the non-working apps

```
                       <headerType>gui</headerType>
                        <outfile>target/${winName}.exe</outfile>
                        <jar>target/${artifactId}-${version}-jar-with-dependencies.jar</jar> <!-- 'shaded' is the value set on shadedClassifierName above -->
                        <errTitle>Erreur lors du lancement du logiciel</errTitle>
                        <classPath>  
                          <mainClass>fr.boot.BootStrap</mainClass>
                        </classPath>
                        <singleInstance>
                            <mutexName>${winName}</mutexName>
                            <windowTitle>${winName}</windowTitle>
                        </singleInstance>
                        <dontWrapJar>false</dontWrapJar>
                        <customProcName>false</customProcName>
                        <jre>
                            <minVersion>1.6.0</minVersion>
                            <initialHeapSize>10</initialHeapSize>
                            <maxHeapSize>500</maxHeapSize>
                        </jre>
                        <versionInfo>
                            <fileVersion>${winVersion}.0</fileVersion>
                            <txtFileVersion>${winVersion}.0</txtFileVersion>
                            <fileDescription>Tool</fileDescription>
                            <copyright>c</copyright>
                            <productVersion>${winVersion}.0</productVersion>
                            <txtProductVersion>${winVersion}.0</txtProductVersion>
                            <productName>${winName}</productName>
                            <internalName>${winName}</internalName>
                            <originalFilename>${winName}.exe</originalFilename>
                        </versionInfo>
                    </configuration>
```

I launch them using the same Windows account, there is no rights problem. So i dont know how to solve this.

I have tried to use Launch4j.exe instead of maven plugin here is my export of configuration. Its still doesn't work:

```
<launch4jConfig>
  <dontWrapJar>false</dontWrapJar>
  <headerType>gui</headerType>
  <jar>C:\apps-0.0.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar</jar>
  <outfile>C:\apps.exe</outfile>
  <errTitle></errTitle>
  <cmdLine></cmdLine>
  <chdir></chdir>
  <priority>normal</priority>
  <downloadUrl>http://java.com/download</downloadUrl>
  <supportUrl></supportUrl>
  <customProcName>false</customProcName>
  <stayAlive>false</stayAlive>
  <manifest></manifest>
  <icon></icon>
  <singleInstance>
    <mutexName>apps</mutexName>
    <windowTitle>apps</windowTitle>
  </singleInstance>
  <classPath>
    <mainClass>fr.core.BootStrap</mainClass>
    <cp>fr.core.BootStrap</cp>
  </classPath>
  <jre>
    <path></path>
    <minVersion>1.6.0</minVersion>
    <maxVersion></maxVersion>
    <jdkPreference>preferJre</jdkPreference>
    <opt>-Denv.java.home=&quot;%JAVA_HOME%&quot;</opt>
  </jre>
  <versionInfo>
    <fileVersion>1.0.0.0</fileVersion>
    <txtFileVersion>1.0.0.0</txtFileVersion>
    <fileDescription>desc</fileDescription>
    <copyright>e</copyright>
    <productVersion>1.0.0.0</productVersion>
    <txtProductVersion>1.0.0.0</txtProductVersion>
    <productName>apps.exe</productName>
    <companyName>appsComp</companyName>
    <internalName>apps</internalName>
    <originalFilename>apps.exe</originalFilename>
  </versionInfo>
</launch4jConfig>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To launch your app with custom process name in launch4J config file must be written

```
<customProcName>true</customProcName>
```

In your non-working app config this parameter is `false`.
Try to change it first.

Comment: I dont know why it doesent work the first try I made, maybe i had an other option in conflict. But customProcName work. the strange fact is that my other maven project doesn't have this option but the .exe got the right naming?!

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment on the maven part, but I have sucessfully used Launch4j with Ant. Take a look at the XML files that are passed to launch4j when building the executable. Most likely the second one specifies dontWrapJar = true.

Alternately load the XML in Launch4j GUI and check that checkbox "Don't wrap the JAR" is *not* checked.

Comment: May be not `dontWrapJar = true` but `customProcName=false`

Comment: Maybe, I find the question is rather vaguely worded.

Comment: Well i have try to set dontWrapJar=false and customProcName=false (even if its default value) and the problem is still there.

Comment: You have specified singleInstance = true, and the mutex name is derived from ${winName}. Possibly the winName is the same for both programs and the first hasn't exited yet?

Comment: the winName is not the same for both programs. Thus i will delete this line because the mutex doesn't work, i can launch as instance as i want, but its not the probleme here :)